# Create single PHP Function for similar queries but with different WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if this is doable or not, and I'm not entirely sure how to search for this. I have several dynamic web pages that all link to the same MySQL database table, but pull different results. So for example, a dynamic web page with ID = 5 will run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE category1 = 1
```

The web page where ID = 7 will run:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE category2 = 1
```

And so on. The queries are all grabbing the data from the same table, but the WHERE clause is different for each query - its not looking at the same column. The page with ID 7 should ONLY be returning results where category2 = 1, and ignoring the results that would be returned for the page with id = 5. My website has about 20 different pages/queries like this which is why I'm looking to see if it can be done in a function instead.

Is there a way I can put that into a function, and if so, how would I set up the parameters correctly? Or is this an instance where I will have to just write out all the queries separately on each page?

```
function find_results(what to put here?) {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (how to code this part?)";    
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
confirm_query ($result);
return $result;
```

}

Comment: using variables? `$where = "category1";` `"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE {$where} = 1"` . The query is a string and can store whatever kind of variables you want. Just get the ID, pass it to find_results, use a switch case or something like that and build your dynamic query. Also, prepare the statement BEFORE querying it in order to avoid potential sql injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would add the necessary parameters to your functions argument list, then provide the values at runtime.

```
function find_results($column, $value) 
{
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE {$column} = $value";    
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query ($result);
    return $result;
}

//Usage:
$result = find_results("category2", 1)
```

If the value you are returning records by ever ends up being a string make sure your wrap `$value` in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

if its a constant relation between pageId and categoryId, you can just create an array to hold it indexed by pageId like:

```
$pageIdToCategoryMapping = [
    1 => 'cateogory1',
    2 => 'category5',
    ...
]
```

and then just use it to pass data to your function like

```
find_results($pageIdToCategoryMapping[$pageId])

function find_results($category) {
(...)
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ({$category} = 1)";  
(...)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using class and object methods for mysql operations. source code available in [github](https://github.com/narayangt/phpTable)

I would recommend you to pass array as an argument and can return query or result as array in format you required. And this function will work any number or condition

```
<?php
$arg['db']="database";
$arg['tabe']="table";
$arg['search']['id1']="id1";
$arg['search']['id2']="id2";
//
function searchAndReturnResultAsArray($arg)
{
    $return = NULL;
    $query="SELECT * FROM ".$arg['table'];
    $flag=false;
    foreach($arg['search'] as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($flag)
            $query.=" AND ";
        else
            $flag=true;
        $query.= $key." = '".$value."' ";
    }
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $field = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
    if($row >= 1)
    {
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array())
        {
            $return[] = $data;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
?>
```

Or alternatively you can just return query once it is ready.